# How to append comments next to each line in a json string?

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I want to create a markdown file which includes a `js` object.
I want to add commentaries which are stored in an other object to each line.

The output should look like this:

```json
{
  "a": "test,  //commentary1
  "b": "test2" //commentary2
}
```

My first intention was to rewrite the `stringify` function, but it's a bit tricky for edge cases.

How can I achieve this functionality in more better way?

Comment: So do I understand correctly that you want to serialize an object while adding comments to each/some of the lines?

Comment: Did you know that the JSON format doesn't support comments?

Comment: Here's an absolutely zero edge-case checked solution: https://jsfiddle.net/f1hzwLbu/

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for that! This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can opt for 2 options

1. Add comment as keys like

   {
   "_comment": "comment text goes here..."
   }
2. Instead of json object use json array and parse accordingly

   {
   "a": ["test", "commentary1"],
   "b": ["test2", "commentary2"]
   }